# How to emit an event after 5 minutes have elapsed for each item (relative to items timestamp)?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've a bunch of items (below) which is getting fetched using a service.

I'm using json server to push and fetch items from local db.json file.

so each items are getting pushed to the local database using json-server.

when pushing each items the timestamp also gets attached to the item.

The idea behind the app is to keep track of the items. So let's say if 5 minutes have elapsed after pushing the item(relative to the timestamp of the item e.g. items[index_of_some_item].time & not relative to the creation of componenet).

So after creating the item when the current time is 5 mins past the time of item in the array, app emits an event for that particular item (like a message, '5 mins have passed for item[1]... like so).

this way the app will emit notification messages for each item (when 5 mins has elapsed after creation of that particular item... somewhat like an alarm)

```
"items": [
    {
      "item": "foo",
      "hint": "bar",
      "time": 1589446462047,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "item": "foo1",
      "hint": "bar1",
      "time": 1589446462047,
      "id": 2
    },


...


]
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to emit an event when the time of an item has elapsed 5 minutes (this should be achieved by comparing with the timestamp of the item).

How can I do that with rxjs in angular?

**NOTE**
I could have achieved something like that with the timer.

```
timer(300000).pipe(// do something)
```

But the problem with this approach is that it starts counting when the component is initialized.

What I want to achieve is that I want to keep track of each item's timestamp, so that if it has passed 5 minutes an event will be fired...

This is what I've tried: but it;'s of no use

```
    of(this.item.time).pipe(tap(time =>
    {

      if (Date.now() === time + 300000)
      {
        console.log('time has passed');
      }
    })
    ).subscribe();
```

So I want to achive is something like this when Date.now() === time + 300000 :-

```
when

Date.now() === time + 300000

// do something
```

I want to fire an event.

**NOTE AGAIN**

I don't want to do something relative to the creation of the component. This is because If I close the app and continue working with it again the setInterval will get again kicked in for each previously created component. This is not fair.

But if we are observing the timestamp of items from the json-server db file it will be relative to the item's timestamp. & as time elapses new messages will be fired for each items. Which is the right way of keep tracking items.

**MENTAL PICTURE**

To get a clear understanding of the app,

Let's imaging a TODO app.
So each new items will be pushed to the local json-server db.json file.
& all these new additions will also get reflected in the template.
So let's say if I've added 10 items to the to do app. (assume that this only takes a couple of seconds).

Then I close the app (browser).

Later I come back after 4 minutes & reopens that app (in browser).

Now since after 5 minutes have passed for each items I will be able to see a notification 5 minutes have passed.

Now If I input another 7 items again, then after 5 minutes I will be able to see a message 5 minutes have passed for those 7 items & 10 minutes have passed for the previous 10 items, like so... if I input another 4 items I will get a message after 15 minutes that 15 minutes have passed for first 10 items 10 minutes for the second 7 items and 5 minutes for the latest 4 items. and this keeeps onnnn goinggg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my reasoning:

- main source consists of 2 observables:

  - existent$ - data received from the server
  - newItem - a subject that emits every time a new item is created
- `delayWhen` operator - will emit the notification for this item based on its time

```js
const BACKOFFTIME = 1000 * 60 * 5;

// Assumed that `getItemsFromServer()` returns Item[]
// `mergeAll` is used to emit each item individually
const existentItems$ = getItemsFromServer().pipe(mergeAll());
const newItem = new Subject<Item>();

merge(
  existentItems$,
  newItem.pipe(
    // `addRawItemToDB` returns `Observable<Item>`
    mergeMap(item => addRawItemToDB(item))
  )
).pipe(
  delayWhen(item => {
    const { time: setAt } = item;
    const now = Date.now();
    const delta = now - setAt;

    const needsToSendNotif = delta < BACKOFFTIME;
    const toWait = needsToSendNotif ? setAt + BACKOFFTIME - now : 0;

    return timer(toWait);
  }),
  map(
    item => ({ 
      ...item, 
      minutesShown: Math.floor((Date.now() - item.time) / BACKOFFTIME),
    })
  ),
  filter(item => item.minutesShown >= 5),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setInterval for each object while it has been created.

```
setInterval(function (referenceToObject) {
    runYourFunction(referenceToObject);
}, 1000*60*5);
```

Or set infinitive loop checking for timestamp of all objects and calling function if timestamp is bigger.

Pseudocode:

```
while(true):
  sleep 1 second
  getAllItems.foreach():
    if(differenceOfNowAndTimestamp > 5 minutes):
      runFunction()
      removeElement or changeTimestampOfElement
```

Comment: I don't want to do something relative to the creation of the component. This is because If I close the app and continue working with it the setInterval will get again kicked in. This is not fair. 

But if we are observing the timestamp of items from the json-server db file it will be relative to the item's timestamp. Which is the right way of keep tracking items.

Comment: You need infinitive loop or any process checking every fixed interval (for example 1 second) timestamp of items.